# Access VBA exit a called sub and skip the rest of the sub

Tags: vba, exit

I have a sub `CreaNewT` as below to create a new table. In `CreatNewT` I call a public sub `ChecTabl` to check if this table exists already.

```
Sub CreaNewT()

Dim ...
Dim ...

Call ChecTabl("TableName")
...
```

In `ChecTabl` I have

```
Dim TS As TableDefs
Dim T As TableDef

Set TS = CurrentDb.TableDefs

For Each T In TS
    If T.Name = Str_Tabl Then
        MsgBox "This table already exists. Please choose another table name.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next
```

I wrote `Exit Sub` because I would like to exit `ChecTabl` and the sub that calls it if this table already exists. However, it only stops executing `ChecTabl` and continues with the rest of `CreaNewT`. How I can code so that it stops executing `ChecTabl` and the sub that calls it? Thanks

Comment: Make `ChecTabl` a function and return False if the table already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Tim, I changed `ChecTabl` into a boolean function. I can check its returned value and decide whether to exit the sub that calls this function.

```
Public Function ChecTabl(Str_Tabl As String) As Boolean

    Dim TS As TableDefs
    Dim T As TableDef

    Set TS = CurrentDb.TableDefs

    For Each T In TS
        If T.Name = Str_Tabl Then
            MsgBox "This table already exists. Please choose another table name.", vbOKOnly
            ChecTabl = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

    ChecTabl = False

Exit_Func:
    Set TS = Nothing
    Set T = Nothing

End Function
```